# Check if words from an Excel column can be found in another Excel Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm stuck on a Python code here.
I have two Excel columnns and my intention is to search through each row in Column[Names] and if there is match for any word in Column[Words].
Remove the text from the applicable row in Column[Names] and return the remaining characters/words into another column.

[image]

So the result I should be having is

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas' `read_excel` function to load your spreadsheet:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('spreadsheet.xslx')
```

You can then create a new column called 'Result' from 'Names':

```
df['Result']=df['Names']
```

You can then iterate over the dataframe and replace the words from the 'Words' column with "", effectively removing them from the sentence:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row['Result']=row['Result'].replace(row['Words'], "")
```

**EDIT:**

Replacing all occurrences of the words in the Words column is even easier!

```
for word in df['Words'].to_list():
    df['Result']=df['Result'].replace(word, "", regex=True)
```

Finally you can export the 'Result' column/series to a new dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I wanted the code to iterate through Column[Words] and remove every matching word. Its not limited to the applicable row.

Comment: My bad! I updated my answer to take this into account.